# If a system has energy which is inversely proportional to temperature. What can be said about this kind of system. What about its specific heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

Can we model a canonical ensemble for this system?
Please answer this question in context of statistical physics.

Comment: Do you mean $E \propto A/T$, with $A>0$?

Comment: Typically we have PV=nRT meaning energy is linearly proportional to temperature. This is true for most spatial relations like thermal expansion, volume etc. With chemistry we typically have exp(-Ea/RT) terms not simple 1/T terms. If something is inversely proportional to distance (such as diffusion and ?capacitance?) then you can expect 1/T terms

Comment: Yes! GiorgioP . I mean the same you said.